# Python3 : Records not getting pushed to Splunk

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.6, splunk

I have created a custom class, which push my logs to splunk, but somehow it is not working. Here is the class.

```
class Splunk(logging.StreamHandler):
  def __init__(self, url, token):
    super().__init__()
    self.url = url
    self.headers = {f'Authorization': f'Splunk {token}'}
    self.propagate = False

  def emit(self, record):
    mydata = dict()
    mydata['sourcetype'] = 'mysourcetype'
    mydata['event'] = record.__dict__
    response = requests.post(self.url, data=json.dumps(mydata), headers=self.headers)
    return response
```

I call the class from my logger class, somehow like this (adding additional handler), so that it can log on console along with send to splunk

```
if splunk_config is not None:
    splunk_handler = Splunk(splunk_config["url"], splunk_config["token"])
    self.default_logger.addHandler(splunk_handler)
```

But somehow, I am not able to see any logs in splunk. Though I can see the logs in console.
When I try to run the strip down version of above logic from python3 terminal, it is successful.

```
import requests
import json 

url = 'myurl'
token = 'mytoken'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Splunk mytoken'}
propagate = False
mydata = dict()
mydata['sourcetype'] = 'mysourcetype'
mydata['event'] = {'name': 'root', 'msg': 'this is a sample message'}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(mydata), headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Things I have already tried, making my dictionary data as JSON serializable using below link but it didn't helped.

https://pynative.com/make-python-class-json-serializable/

Any other things to try ?

Comment: `json.dumps()` serializes it as a string, try to use `json=mydata` as the argument to your post, which adds a `content-type` header automatically

Comment: Sorry I realize this is very old.

Can you add what error information you are getting back when things don't work? Is it an authorization error (you need to correct HEC token). Or are you getting an internal server error from Splunk? Possibly the format of your JSON isn't right.

I have been using the Splunk HEC event collector REST API and that works well. I'm basically just doing what the CURL samples in Splunk say to do, but doing that with rhe requests API in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully used this Python Class for Sending Events to Splunk HTTP Event Collector instead of writing a dedicated class

https://github.com/georgestarcher/Splunk-Class-httpevent

Advantage is that it implements batchEvent() and flushBatch() methods to submit multiple events at once across multiple threads.

The example here should get you started:

https://github.com/georgestarcher/Splunk-Class-httpevent/blob/master/example.py

*If this answers your question, take a moment to accept the answer. This can be done by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in!*